# Accessing AppCompatActivity in custom native module

Tags: java, android, react-native

Currently building a custom native module using Braintree Android SDK v3 for use in react-native. The SDK initialization required a parameter of type AppCompatActivity or Fragment. I'm having trouble finding a way to pass that parameter as there doesn't seem to exist a method that returns the correct type.

The compile error:

```sh
this.mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(getCurrentActivity(), token);
                                                 ^
method BraintreeFragment.newInstance(AppCompatActivity,String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Activity cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity)

method BraintreeFragment.newInstance(Fragment,String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Activity cannot be converted to Fragment)
```

I've tried to replace

```java
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
```

with

```java
public class MainApplication extends AppCompatActivity implements ReactApplication {
```

in MainApplication.java, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem, and leads to some other errors.

Hoping someone could assists.

**Edit: Clarification regarding project setup.**

React-Native v0.60.5

Files:

```
java/com/my.app/MainActivity.java
java/com/my.app/MainApplication.java
java/com/my.app/braintree/BraintreePackage.java
java/com/my.app/braintree/BraintreeModule.java
```

MainAcitivity.java

```java
package com.my.app;

// Default
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

// Custom added
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;



public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "appname";
    }

    /**
     * Injects build number as prop to root app component in react
     */
    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
                Bundle initialProps = getMyLaunchOptions();
                return initialProps;
            }
        };
    }
    protected Bundle getMyLaunchOptions() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        PackageInfo pInfo = null;
        try {
            pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            int build = pInfo.versionCode;
            bundle.putString("build", String.valueOf(build));
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

MainApplication.java

```java
package com.my.app;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptExecutorFactory;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.List;

// Native Braintree
import com.my.app.braintree.BraintreePackage;


public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());

      // Custom Native Braintree
      packages.add(new BraintreePackage());

      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

BraintreePackage.java

```java
package com.my.app.braintree;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class BraintreePackage implements ReactPackage {

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();
    modules.add(new BraintreeModule(reactContext));
    return modules;
  }
}
```

BraintreeModule.java

```java
package com.my.app.braintree;


import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;

import android.content.Context;

// Braintree
import com.braintreepayments.api.*;
import com.braintreepayments.api.exceptions.*;

public class BraintreeModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  private String token;
  private Context mActivityContext;
  private BraintreeFragment mBraintreeFragment;

  public BraintreeModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "BraintreeModule";
  }

  public String getToken() {
    return this.token;
  }

  public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
  }

  // Initializes instance with client token
  @ReactMethod
  public void setup(
    final String clientToken,
    final Callback successCallback,
    final Callback errorCallback
  ) {
    try {
      this.mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(getCurrentActivity(), clientToken);
      // Set token
      this.setToken(clientToken);
      successCallback.invoke(this.getToken());
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException e) {
      errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Put `BraintreeFragment.newInstance` in an Activity, not in your Application class. It doesn't belong there.

Comment: @Zun Appreciate the input. The Braintree module is in a separate file. I've updated  the question with current java-files.